# Cannot currently modify this text in the editor. It is readonly

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, debugging

In VS2008, in a VB.NET windows (WInform)  app, I suddenly seem to not be able to edit the code and continue in this project.

In Tools-->Option, Edit and continue is checked.

What else can I look for? The files I am trying to modify are not Read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another application probably has a write lock on the file. Restart your PC, or use Process Explorer to find out which process has a handle on the file.

Answer (score 1):

go to Tools >> Import-Export settings and select reset all settings. 
Hope, This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below procedure
Go to
 `PROJECT` -- > `PRPORTIES` -- > `COMPILE` -- > `ADVANCE COMPILE OPTIONS` 
--- > select `TARGET CPU X86`

This should solve the problem.